# Android: Using Robotium for extracting GUI tree

Tags: android, user-interface, robotium

[Robotium](http://code.google.com/p/robotium/) is a tool which is great for black box testing. I was wondering is it possible that I extract the GUI tree of an app with Robotium.?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `getRootView()` to get the root layout of an `Activity` .